# If $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n | w_j|^2 \leq 1$ implies $ \left| \sum\limits_{j=1}^n z_j w_j \right| \leq 1$, then $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n | z_j|^2 \leq 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to show following.

Fix $n$ a positive integer. Suppose that $z_1, \cdots z_n$ are complex numbers satisfying
\begin{align}
  \left| \sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j \right| \leq 1
\end{align}
for all $w_1, \cdots, w_n\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n | w_j|^2 \leq 1$. then,  $\sum_{j=1}^n | z_j|^2 \leq 1$.

Any idea or hint will be helpful.

---

adopting from hint i got for 
\begin{align}
|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j | = |\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda |z_j|^2| = |\lambda| \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2 \leq1
\end{align}
 and form 
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n |w_j|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n |\lambda|^2 |z_j|^2  = |\lambda|^2 \sum_{j=1}^n  |z_j|^2 \leq1
\end{align}
Then the equality seems to be depend on value of $\lambda$. $i.e$, i have

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2 \leq \frac{1}{|\lambda|}, \qquad  \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2 \leq \frac{1}{|\lambda|^2}
\end{align}
which i don't know how to interpret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n|z_j|^2=\lambda^2\gt1\tag{1}
$$
for real $\lambda\gt1$. Define
$$
w_j=\frac{\overline{z}_j}\lambda\tag{2}
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n|w_j|^2=1\tag{3}
$$
However,
$$
\left|\,\sum_{j=1}^nz_jw_j\,\right|=\lambda\gt1\tag{4}
$$
Thus, if
$$
\left|\,\sum_{j=1}^nz_jw_j\,\right|\le1\tag{5}
$$
for all $w_j$ so that $(3)$ holds, we must have
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n|z_j|^2\le1\tag{6}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try $w_j=\lambda \overline{z_j}$.

Comment: adopting your hint i got for $|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j | = |\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda |z_j|^2| \leq1$, and form $\sum_{j=1}^n |w_j|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n |\lambda|^2 |z_j|^2 \leq1$,  Then the equality seems to be depend on value of $\lambda$.