# For given $\sum_{j=1}^n | w_j|^2 \leq 1$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n | z_j|^2 \leq 1$ implies $ \left| \sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j \right| \leq 1 $

Tags: complex-analysis

Now little bit twist the problem ( I want to do with converse way of my previous question [If $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n | w_j|^2 \leq 1$ implies $ \left| \sum\limits_{j=1}^n z_j w_j \right| \leq 1$, then $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n | z_j|^2 \leq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930236/for-given-left-sum-j-1n-z-j-w-j-right-leq-1-with-sum-j-1n-w))

Situation is similar.

Fix $n$ a positive integer. Suppose that $z_1, \cdots z_n$, $w_1, \cdots w_n$ are complex numbers satisfying
 $\sum_{j=1}^n | w_j|^2 \leq 1$.and $\sum_{j=1}^n | z_j|^2 \leq 1$. then 
is following true
\begin{align}
  \left| \sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j \right| \leq 1
\end{align}

It seems that above equality true. $i.e$, pick $w_j = \bar{z}_j$ then it became trivial, but i am not sure for proving such inequality in this fashion.

Comment: It's not using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: It is exactly the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.