# Inequality from complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been struggling with the following inequality:

Let $\lbrace z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n \rbrace$ and $\lbrace w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n \rbrace$ be complex numbers. Let

$$
|\sum_j z_jw_j| \leq 1,
$$

and $\sum_j |w_j|^2 \leq 1$. Prove that $\sum_j |z_j|^2 \leq 1$.

I tried several things, including Cauchy-Schwartz inequality but I couldn't prove it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your claim is False. Consider 
\begin{align}
\{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\} = \{1, 0, \ldots, 0\}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n\} = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, it's equal to 1. That doesn't break the hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry, I meant http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930236/if-sum-limits-j-1n-w-j2-leq-1-implies-left-sum-limits-j-1n-z

Comment: Then what's your question? The post you cite already has answers.

Comment: I just found it, and there is a proof for the exercise, without saying that it cannot be fulfilled. One of you two must be wrong...

Comment: Your original question is different from the question of that post. We are correct.

Comment: Copied wrong...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56402/discussion-between-user2820579-and-jacky-chong).